# What is the correct html code to access Blockly Factory code?

Tags: javascript, html, blockly

Using VSCode and Block Factory [https://blockly-demo.appspot.com/static/demos/blockfactory/index.html].

I've have this in index.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    ...
      body {
        background-color: #fff;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      h1 {
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 140%;
        margin: 10px;
      }
      #defineBlocksWithJsonArray {
        float: bottom;
        height: 90%;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="defineBlocksWithJsonArray"></div>
    <script>
      var toolbox = "color_rgb";
      var workspace = Blockly.inject('defineBlocksWithJsonArray', {toolbox: toolbox});
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In index.js (Block Factory code):

```
'use strict';
Blockly.defineBlocksWithJsonArray([
{
  "type": "color_rgb",
  "message0": "Red %1 Green %2 Blue %3",
  "args0": [
    {
      "type": "input_value",
      "name": "RED"
    },
    {
      "type": "input_value",
      "name": "GREEN"
    },
    {
      "type": "input_value",
      "name": "BLUE"
    }
  ],
  "output": null,
  "colour": 230,
  "tooltip": "",
  "helpUrl": ""
}
]);
javascript.javascriptGenerator.forBlock['color_rgb'] = function(block, generator) {
  var value_red = generator.valueToCode(block, 'RED', javascript.Order.ATOMIC);
  var value_green = generator.valueToCode(block, 'GREEN', javascript.Order.ATOMIC);
  var value_blue = generator.valueToCode(block, 'BLUE', javascript.Order.ATOMIC);
  // TODO: Assemble javascript into code variable.
  var code = '...';
  // TODO: Change ORDER_NONE to the correct strength.
  return [code, Blockly.javascript.ORDER_NONE];
};
```

A debug console error message -> https://snipboard.io/i5gmtQ.jpg.

I'm new to JavaScript and to Blockly.  What is the correct html code to access the Block Factory code?

Answer (score 0):

Change index.html to:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Toolbox Customization Codelab</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/blockly/blockly.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="toolbox_style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <style>
      html,
      body {
        height: 100%;
      }
      body {
        background-color: #ffffff;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      h1 {
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 140%;
        margin: 10px;
      }
      #blocklyDiv {
        float: bottom;
        height: 90%;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="blocklyDiv"></div>
    <script>
      const toolbox = {
        kind: 'flyoutToolbox',
        contents: [
          {
            kind: 'block',
            type: 'color_rgb'
          }]
      }
      const workspace = Blockly.inject('blocklyDiv', {toolbox: toolbox});
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```